# Netty SSL / TLS / HTTPS support

Tags: java, ssl, netty

Adding support for encryption over netty channels using SSL.

Need some references and example codes.

Doc http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/guide/pdf/netty.pdf only refers that its possible using SSLHandler.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the Netty bug tracker.

Comment: @Deejay what Netty bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer the secure chat[[1](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/package-summary.html)] example in the "examples"[[2](http://www.jboss.org/netty/documentation.html#examples)] section of netty.

Comment: [Why links are not good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)